# What is problem domain classes and problem domain object?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Consider following scenario
"When customer call the office and give the hire details,the receptionist should be able to add the details to  the system.An SMS containing the reservation details will be sent to the customer after making the reservation."

Above scenario is a part of my software engineering assignment and the are asking to write down the problem domain objects but i have no idea what problem domain objects are?Can someone explain this.

Comment: How about consulting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_domain ?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell anything substantial you find around a problem domain is considered a domain object. In your case you have the receptionist, the SMS, the reservation and the customer. Now what you are doing is to classify these objects (make classes). And that's called problem domain analysis. There are thick books available about how to go further from here.